# Download a file from TFS based on Change Set Number

Tags: c#, .net

I want to download two different versions of a file. I already got the history of the file and got the first and last Changeset numbers.

Now I am trying to download the files using `VersionControl.DownloadFile` method, so that I can do a comparision. But I am not able to identify the VersionSpec. Any help?

**Sample Code:**

> ```
>         string tfsPath = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
>
>         var histories = vcs.QueryHistory( //filepath
>                tfsPath,
>                VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.OneLevel, null, null, null, Int32.MaxValue, true, false, true).Cast<Changeset>();
>
>         Changeset first = null;
>         Changeset last = null;
>
>         if (histories.Count() > 0)
>         {
>             first = histories.Where(h => h.ChangesetId > changeSetId).First();
>             last = histories.Where(h => h.ChangesetId > changeSetId).Last();
>         }
>
>         //I want to compare these two versions
> ```

Comment: "But I am not able to identify the VersionSpec." What do you mean exactly,that you don't know what version of the file, or how to define the VersionSpec?

Comment: DownloadFile method expects that parameter. It is used to specify which version we need to download. But I don't know how to initialize that parameter.

Comment: See if my answer below helps, instead of passing in VersionSpec.Latest you would pass in "versionFrom" in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify a particular change set into VersionSpec you can use [ParseSingleSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
//for changeset 13    
VersionSpec versionFrom = VersionSpec.ParseSingleSpec("C13", null);
```

[For some hints on the "version" format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e.aspx#versionspec)